# apache httpclient 4.4: HostnameVerifier transition from 4.3.x

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

HttpClient 4.3 had three static variables in `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory`:

1. STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
2. BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
3. ALLOW_ALL__HOSTNAME_VERIFIER

When upgrading the dependency to version 4.4 of HttpClient, I see that all the above constants are deprecated. The deprecation note in JavaDoc mentioned to use `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier`. Reading the docs, I assume that `DefaultHostnameVerifier` is a direct replacement to `STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`. Also the `ALLOW_ALL__HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` is easy to implement:

```
package org.wiztools.restclient.http;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

/**
 *
 * @author subwiz
 */
public class AllowAllHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

There is a subtle distinction between the `STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` and `BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` (from JavaDoc):

> The only difference between BROWSER_COMPATIBLE and STRICT is that a wildcard (such as "*.foo.com") with BROWSER_COMPATIBLE matches all subdomains, including "a.b.foo.com".

Do we have a readily available `BROWSER_COMPATIBLE` hostname verifier for httpclient 4.4?

Answer (score 17):

Actually, the javadoc of [AllowAllHostnameVerifier](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.html) gives a direct replacement for `ALLOW_ALL__HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`, which is [NoopHostnameVerifier](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/NoopHostnameVerifier.html) .

Comment: I was looking for the non-deprecated way to do `ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER ` and the `NoopHostnameVerifier` worked. Just replace the the second parameter of the function with an instance of that class, so: `SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory( sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());`

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a new implementation class for `AllowAllHostnameVerifier` and don't need another implementation for `BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier`, simply pass an instance to the new [DefaultHostnameVerifier](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.html),

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new DefaultHostnameVerifier());
```

this class the neccesary verification methods for both with the following method signatures

```
public final boolean verify(String host, SSLSession session) (Override)
```

and

```
public final void verify(String host, X509Certificate cert) throws SSLException
```

in the second method the httpcomponents does a checking for matching subdomains

```
public final void verify(String host, X509Certificate cert) throws SSLException {
    boolean ipv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(host);
    boolean ipv6 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv6Address(host);
    int subjectType = ((ipv4) || (ipv6)) ? 7 : 2;
    List subjectAlts = extractSubjectAlts(cert, subjectType);
    if ((subjectAlts != null) && (!(subjectAlts.isEmpty()))) {
        if (ipv4)
            matchIPAddress(host, subjectAlts);
        else if (ipv6)
            matchIPv6Address(host, subjectAlts);
        else {
            matchDNSName(host, subjectAlts, this.publicSuffixMatcher);
        }
    } else {
        X500Principal subjectPrincipal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal();
        String cn = extractCN(subjectPrincipal.getName("RFC2253"));
        if (cn == null) {
            throw new SSLException("Certificate subject for <" + host + "> doesn't contain " + "a common name and does not have alternative names");
        }

        matchCN(host, cn, this.publicSuffixMatcher);
    }
}
```

take a look at the source code for more clarification

[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.java/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier` was essentially IE 5/6 compatible implementation. I am no sure if it is actually compatible with more modern browser applications. `BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier` should have never existed in the first place and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I read all this and nothing worked for me, here's what saved my day: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507502/3090309

I was using:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
```