# Why do I receive a connection reset when I tried to accept my SSL certificate using HTTPclient?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I tried to accept my certificate to test my REST api.
For that, I tried :

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts
        .custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new File(KEYSTORE_PATH), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,
                new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();
try {
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(BASE_URL);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient
            .execute(postRequest);
    // try {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    // } finally {
    // response.close();
    // }
} finally {
    closeableHttpClient.close();
}
```

The error happen when I do `closeableHttpClient.execute(postRequest);`

Variables are :

```
private static final String KEYSTORE_PATH = System.getProperty("java.home")
        + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
private static final char[] KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "changeit".toCharArray();
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9010/api";
```

note : I do not have a domain name, i'm on localhost.
If I understood the error well it's my SSLConnectionSocketFactory closed too early. But I don't know how and why.

EDIT : I'm using HTTPClient. 
If I update the port HTTP to HTTPS, I receive another error : `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'localhost' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer`

Comment: Are you using Apache HttpClient? If so, say that *somewhere* in your question, e.g. tag it.

Comment: I've edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here : [javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655031/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-host-name-does-not-match-the-certifica) 
My code is now :

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts
        .custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new File(KEYSTORE_PATH), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,
                new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslcontext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder
        .<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
        .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
        .register("https", sslsf).build();

final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
        registry);
cm.setMaxTotal(100);
```

It's working but I'm still working on it (understand and find if I can do something else/better)! Thanks